# Enrich an inner class

Tags: scala, inner-classes, implicit, enrich-my-library

I want to implement the enrich-my-library pattern for the inner class that will work for any instance of the outer class. Something like this:

```scala
class Outer {
  class Inner(val x: Option[Inner] = None) {
    def test(y: Inner) {}
  }
}

implicit class ExtInner(inner: Outer#Inner) {
  def get = inner.x.get
}

val outer = new Outer
val inner = new outer.Inner(Some(new outer.Inner))
inner.test(inner.get)
```

This code will not compile, because of the type mismatch: `get` returns an object of type `Outer#Inner` but `test` expects `outer.Inner`.

I have two ways to make it work but both involve the use of `asInstanceOf` which I would like to avoid. The first one is simply to cast the result of `get` to `outer.Inner`:

```scala
inner.test(inner.get.asInstanceOf[outer.Inner])
```

The second is a bit more generic and does the casting in `ExtInner`:

```scala
implicit class ExtInner[T <: Outer#Inner](inner: T) {
  def get = inner.x.get.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Is there a better way to enrich an inner class so there will be no need to do the casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
object Test extends App {
  class Outer {
    class Inner(val x: Option[Inner] = None) {
      def test(y: Inner) { println(s"$toString testing $y") }
    }
    implicit class ExtInner(val inner: Inner) {
      def get = inner.x.get
    }
  }

  val outer = new Outer
  val inner = new outer.Inner(Some(new outer.Inner))
  import outer._
  inner.test(inner.get)
}
```

or just enhance outer's Inners:

```
  implicit class ExtInner(val inner: outer.Inner) {
    def get = inner.x.get
  }
```

Also, I sense that you can invoke the method this way, but it will not infer the singleton type param outer.type in order to summon the implicit.

```
  implicit class ExtInner[A <: Outer with Singleton](val inner: A#Inner) {
    def get: A#Inner = inner.x.get
  }
  inner.test(ExtInner[outer.type](inner).get)
```

Comment: Pimp my library pattern assumes that the `Outer` class can't be modified so taking the `ExtInner` inside the `Outer` class is not really a solution. Having `ExtInner` accept `outer.Inner` instead of  `Outer#Inner` binds it to the concrete instance, which is undesirable because we will need to define a new implicit conversion for each instance of the `Outer` class.

Comment: Then you have to accept my third answer that you can't get the implicit applied. It's analogous to the regex conversion in the Parsers mini-cake, so it must be a common use case. There's always reflection and macros.

Comment: Your third answer does the job without casting although it requires a bit of boilerplate code. Can you comment on why we need `with Singleton`, it seems to work without it as well?